# Plotting independent dataset in matplotlib 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I am interested in plotting independent dataset using `matplotlib`. For that purpose I incorporated the independent data coordinates in column of X, Y and Z.

Consider the following python code-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([[1, 2 ,5], [6, 1, 7]])
Y = np.array([[4, 6, 9], [7, 1, 5]])
Z = np.array([[5, 7, 4], [2, 1, 6]])

fig1, (ax) = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

ax.plot(X, Y, Z)
```

I believed that for two-dimensional array the columns represent separate data sets, but the line `ax.plot(X, Y, Z)` produces the following error-

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original- 
>remapped]: (6,)  and requested shape (2,)
...
AttributeError: 'Line3D' object has no attribute '_verts3d'
```

I can produce the desired output by replacing `ax.plot(X, Y, Z)` with the following-

```
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    ax.plot(X[:, i], Y[:, i], Z[:, i])
```

Is there a way to avoid the loop.

Comment: No, IMHO it is not possible to plot 3 separated line using the **plot()** function without some form of iteration to unpack and pass each line as a separate argument.     
The mentioned *ValueError* typically occurs when trying to work on two arrays that have incompatible shapes…even if X,Y, and Z have same shape (2,3).   
Basically, the issue here is that the **plot()** method tries to plot your 3 arrays as a single line with six data points. I suppose that the shape mismatch error is triggered since the method expects each inputs to have the same shape along the first dimension.

Comment: If all lines shall have different colors, as in your desired output, then plotting in a loop is probably the easiest way. If the lines shall all have the same color and the loop is too slow, you can first stack the x, y and z coords columnwise with `np.nan` to separate the lines and then make one call to `plot` with the stacked arrays. This additional effort only makes sense if you have many lines and plotting in the loop is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** `ax.scatter` works whereas `ax.plot` doesn't; so we can interpolate points and use scatter. The solution is inefficient but removes for loop as required.

For instance, the output from OP's loop-based solution is:
[image]

Now, let us change the line `ax.plot(X, Y, Z)` to `ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)` in OP's original code. For completeness, it is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([[1, 2 ,5], [6, 1, 7]])
Y = np.array([[4, 6, 9], [7, 1, 5]])
Z = np.array([[5, 7, 4], [2, 1, 6]])

fig1, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

ax.scatter(X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel())
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Summarily, `ax.scatter` works unlike `ax.plot`!

Now, if we simply interpolate several points between the end points of the lines, we can achieve a plot that is identical to the intended plot. For completeness, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([[1, 2 ,5], [6, 1, 7]])
Y = np.array([[4, 6, 9], [7, 1, 5]])
Z = np.array([[5, 7, 4], [2, 1, 6]])

N = 1000

interp_points = np.linspace(0, 1, N)

interp_points = interp_points.reshape(-1, 1)

# Interpolated values (total  count: N)
X_interp = X[:-1, :] + interp_points * (X[1:, :] - X[:-1, :])
Y_interp = Y[:-1, :] + interp_points * (Y[1:, :] - Y[:-1, :])
Z_interp = Z[:-1, :] + interp_points * (Z[1:, :] - Z[:-1, :])

fig1, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

ax.scatter(X_interp.T.ravel(), Y_interp.T.ravel(), Z_interp.T.ravel(), s=0.1)   
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

If we want different colors for each line, we can pass a list of colors to the `ax.scatter`, length of list = total number of points, the first N items in the list have the color for first line, and so on. So, using the following, we get:

```
ax.scatter(X_interp.T.ravel(), Y_interp.T.ravel(), Z_interp.T.ravel(), 
            color=['red'] * (N) + ['green'] * (N) + ['blue'] * (N), s=0.1)
```

[image]

Which accomplishes the desired plot without using for loop.